# Flutter : Variables Reset to Default Value when Navigate to another Screen

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I have a problem that some variables in screen reset back to initiated value when I navigate to another screen.

Is there a way to save these variables values even if I  go to another screen?

Comment: do u use any state management pattern ?

Comment: No I  don't use  state management

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to check Flutter official documentation - btw they're great!

Adding Interactivity to your app:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive

Usage of SetState for controlling state of your app: 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

...and some deep dive into State Management in Flutter: 
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt

Comment: I don't exactly understand how is your answer helpfull. There is a strange bug that after hot reload some of the variables are also reset and dispose is not called

Answer (score 1):

To be able to properly save the variables I'ld suggest you to look up for a State Management Architecture for your app. It'll be a lot helpful in long run too. 
I'ld personally suggest **ProviderModel**. If you havent used that before it isnt much difficult to understand.

---

**THE BELOW MENTIONED WAY IS NOT THE RIGHT WAY, AS I SAID ABOVE TO DO IT PROPERLY USE A STATE MANAGEMENT ARCHITECTURE**

**BUT** if in some case you dont want to do that. 
You can make a class object with the member variables as the variables that you are using inside the Widget.

```
class CounterModel{
    int counter;
    CounterModel(){
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

and **onDispose** inside widget you can save a copy of that class object globally. 
Declare a global class object like this

```
CounterModel model;
```

and populate it on dispose.

```
onDispose(){
    model = new CounterModel();
    model.counter = <currentCounter>;
    super.dispose();
}
```

now whenever you build the  widget u can use this global object to access all it values no matter what page you are on.

**BUT AGAIN YOU SHOULD NEVER DO THIS**

Comment: I think  I will go with state management as you advised.. Thanks

Comment: @Aman  Any source code implemented with this approach?